# Internet Access Controller using .net ( vb or c# )

Tags: vb6, connection, controller

I want to develop a software which restricts users internet access using vb6 or vb.net.

This is not a baby sitter program but

1) whenever a client machine takes any browser it should  ask for username and password.

2)There should be option for adding new users at the server side application.

can anyone  suggest any name of such a software. or some sites where I can get some help

on the same..

Comment: You have never accepted a single answer to a question you've asked... why would anyone want to help you out? Most people who answer questions do it to gain reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a HTTP proxy using sockets. You would turn off internet connection sharing on your server and configure the other machines to connect to the web via your proxy.

I would recommend going for an off the self solution e.g. in a router rather than building something from scratch.

If you are dead set on using VB6 you could make use of the winsock control. Here is a project using winsock to serve files. You could modify it to become a multithreaded proxy server instead. It will be a tough challenge though.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/winsock.aspx